# Copy-command fails on second time - but not on first

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, events, post-build-event, post-build

I've created a Post-Build-Event in VS2010 for a project that copies the output *.dll file to another place, on the first build-attempt it builds without errors, but when I then try again, it fails with Error-Code 1 -> `could not load file, because it's used by another process`

post-build-command:

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll" "$(TargetDir)\..\..\..\LanguageContainerC111\bin\output_buildtasks\$(ProjectName).dll"
```

How can i solve this? the first project (where the .dll was generated) has no dependencies, the second that needs the dll has dependencies set to the first project, so why the commmand can fail?

Comment: Start by using procmon.exe/handle/exe/process explorer/... to figure out which process is using the file, then post it here else it's close to impossible to provide a suitable answer.

Comment: it's used by visual studio : devenv.exe | i wouldnt know which other process should use it. Or what do you expect?